# Equivalent of double-clickable .sh and .bat on Mac?

Tags: macos, installation, executable

I am distributing a Java program where I want a double-clickable file to run

```
java -cp MyProgram.jar;MyLib.jar my.program.Main
```

On Windows I simply distribute a .bat file, for *nix an executable .sh file. Problem is, double-clicking the .sh file just opens it up in a text editor on Mac. What should I do for Mac?

Comment: Another useful related question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065069/equivalent-of-bat-in-mac-os.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On mac, there is a specific extension for executing shell scripts by double clicking them: this is `.command`.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but for those getting a `<file>.command could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges.` error, as I was, execute the following on Terminal: `chmod u+x /path/to/file.command` and that should get rid of that problem.

Comment: @user2016436 I don't want to add `chmod u+x`  to run the file, as the executable file will run at the client. what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

For Java applications on Mac, you really should use Apple's Jar Bundler (in the Developer Tools/Applications/Utilities folder; really a symlink to /usr/share/java/Tools/Jar Bundler). It lets you make a proper OS X double-clickable app, including setting preferences for e.g. using the Mac toolbar, JVM version, graphics system, OS X app metadata and classpath/resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a .sh (Shell Script), after all MacOSX is Unix!

Answer (score 1):

The answer about using the Jar Bundler tool is correct, but if you want to use a .sh file, make sure the unix permissions are set properly to something like 755 with CHMOD, and make sure the first line contains the path to a shell installed by default on Mac OS X.  Also note that even with the +x bit set, it may still ask the user whether they want to open it or run it.