# Converting a Windows intended batch to an OSX one

Tags: java, windows, macos, batch-file

I created this batch file on Windows:

```
del /s *.class
javac com\company\bot\client\*.java
javac com\company\bot\server\Main.java

start cmd /k Call runServer.bat 
start cmd /k Call runClient.bat
start cmd /k Call runMyClient.bat
```

Which does the job on Windows, now I want to execute the same batch file on a OSX terminal, but I get the following errors:

```
 maasbommel:BotProgram pmeijer$ ./test.bat
./test.bat: line 1: del: command not found
javac: invalid flag: comcompanybotclient*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
javac: invalid flag: comcompanybotserverMain.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
: command not found 
./test.bat: line 5: start: command not found
./test.bat: line 6: start: command not found
./test.bat: line 7: start: command not found
```

Which kind of makes sense since there is no del command nor cmd in OSX.

So my question is how to convert this properly? I searched the internet for this problem but can not find anything useful. I hope someone can explain the concept to me.

Greetz,

Comment: checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065069/equivalent-of-bat-in-mac-os

Comment: [delete in OSX](https://www.google.de/search?q=osx+delete+file+terminal)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it _should_ work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

You might use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), which actually is a build tool like `make` but cross-platform (XML). This way you have a cross-platform "batch" command processor.

Paying the overhead of needing to install ant.

An overview of [available ant tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html). An ant file would look like:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="run" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>

  <target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean" description="clean up" >
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="compile, clean" description="run all" >
     <java dir="${exec.dir}" jar="${exec.dir}/dist/test.jar"
         fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="128m">
       <arg value="-h"/>
       <classpath>
         <pathelement location="dist/test.jar"/>
         <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
       </classpath>
     </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

Running by ant tasks exec or java.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved this by using IntelliJ's run configurations. Thanks for the answers anyway.